# NGINX: getting subdirectories to work

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

I recently changed to NGINX 1.7.12 from Apache 2.4 and I am coming to love its speed and versatility. Unfortunately, I still haven’t been able to get the SERVER block working correctly.

I am using FASTCGI php5-fpm to serve the php. The root of my NGINX is /var/www. 
The main website called MC is at www.example.com and is served from /var/www/mc

At the same time I have a wordpress blog called “masmagazine” as a subdirectory of the main site www.example.com/masmagazine that is served from /var/www/masmagazine

I have managed to make both websites (the main site and the blog) work via two different server block files – but I am unable to combine them correctly to allow both websites to work at the same time:

Working server block for www.example.com:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name www.example.com;
root /var/www/mc;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}   
location /includes {
    rewrite ^/includes/css/coupon-unit.css /includes/css/coupon-unit.php;
    rewrite ^/includes/css/mobile-menu.css /includes/css/mobile-menu.php;
    rewrite ^/includes/css/mobile.css /includes/css/mobile.php;
    rewrite ^/includes/css/style.css /includes/css/style.php;
    rewrite ^/includes/css/users.css /includes/css/users.php;
}           
location /feed {
    rewrite ^/feed/ /feed.php break;
}
location /internationalsitemap {
    rewrite ^/internationalsitemap.xml /internationalsitemap.php;
}
location /page {
    rewrite ^/page-sitemap.xml /sitemap.php?site=page;
    rewrite ^/page-child-sitemap.xml /sitemap.php?site=childstore;
}
location /newstores {
    rewrite ^/newstores-sitemap.xml /sitemap.php?site=store;
}
location /coupon_category {
    rewrite ^/coupon_category-sitemap.xml /sitemap.php?site=category;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Working server block for www.example.com/masmagazine":

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name www.example.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
root /var/www;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location /masmagazine {
    alias /var/www/masmagazine;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /masmagazine/index.php?$args;
}   

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

When I combine the two, I get 404 not found errors for masmagazine probably because I am not handling the subdirectory (of masmagazine) situation correctly within the php location block etc.

I would be very grateful for any help! I am really stuck on this.

In Apache what worked was:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mc
<Directory /var/www/mc/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /masmagazine /var/www/masmagazine

<Directory  /var/www/masmagazine/>

        Options FollowSymLinks

        AllowOverride All

        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

        Require all granted

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Update:

As per Tero's suggestion, I used this modified server block:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name www.example.com;
root /var/www/mc;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}   

location /masmagazine {
    alias /var/www/masmagazine;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /includes {
    rewrite ^/includes/css/coupon-unit.css /includes/css/coupon-unit.php;
    rewrite ^/includes/css/mobile-menu.css /includes/css/mobile-menu.php;
    rewrite ^/includes/css/mobile.css /includes/css/mobile.php;
    rewrite ^/includes/css/style.css /includes/css/style.php;
    rewrite ^/includes/css/users.css /includes/css/users.php;
}   

location /feed {
    rewrite ^/feed/ /feed.php break;
}

location /internationalsitemap {
    rewrite ^/internationalsitemap.xml /internationalsitemap.php;
}

location /page {
    rewrite ^/page-sitemap.xml /sitemap.php?site=page;
    rewrite ^/page-child-sitemap.xml /sitemap.php?site=childstore;
}

location /newstores {
    rewrite ^/newstores-sitemap.xml /sitemap.php?site=store;
}

location /coupon_category {
    rewrite ^/coupon_category-sitemap.xml /sitemap.php?site=category;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

The result is 404 error when asking for www.example.com/masmagazine. The log shows that the PHP processor is attempting to process the index.php of masmagazine (as per the index directive) from var/www/mc/masmagazine/index.php when it should be looking for it in var/www/masmagazine/index.php.

The relevant parts of the log are:

```
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http request line: "GET /masmagazine/ HTTP/1.1"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http uri: "/masmagazine/"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http args: ""
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http exten: ""
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 test location: "/"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 test location: "internationalsitemap"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 test location: "newstores"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 test location: "masmagazine"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 test location: ~ "\.php$"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 using configuration "/masmagazine"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 access phase: 8
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 access phase: 9
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 access phase: 10
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 access phase: 11
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 post access phase: 12
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 try files phase: 13
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http script var: "/masmagazine/"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 trying to use file: "/" "/var/www/masmagazine/"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http script var: "/masmagazine/"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 trying to use dir: "/" "/var/www/masmagazine/"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 try file uri: "/masmagazine/"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 content phase: 14
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 content phase: 15
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 open index "/var/www/masmagazine/index.php"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 internal redirect: "/masmagazine/index.php?"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 test location: "/"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 test location: "internationalsitemap"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 test location: "newstores"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 test location: "masmagazine"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 test location: ~ "\.php$"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 using configuration "\.php$"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 access phase: 8
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 access phase: 9
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 access phase: 10
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 access phase: 11
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 post access phase: 12
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 try files phase: 13
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http script var: "/masmagazine/index.php"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 trying to use file: "/masmagazine/index.php" "/var/www/mc/masmagazine/index.php"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 trying to use file: "=404" "/var/www/mc=404"2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http finalize request: 404, "/masmagazine/index.php?" a:1, c:2
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http special response: 404, "/masmagazine/index.php?"
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 http set discard body
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 xslt filter header
2015/05/22 12:00:54 [debug] 2108#0: *1 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: Could there be a problem with my try_files statement?

Answer (score 0):

Add this block to your first `server` block:

```
location /masmagazine {
    alias /var/www/masmagazine;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

The `try_files` inside the location blocks works relative to the `location` block root directory, which here is defined using the `alias` statement.

Comment: Thanks Tero - I had already tried adding that and the problem is in the FASTCGI PHP processor block. Please see the original question.